# Regex with positive and negative selection in for loop to iterate through a list of files

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I embarrassingly struggle to iterate through multiple files selected one the basis of multiple criteria (defined by a regex). For example from the files listed below I'd like to select only files with txt extension, except the ones containing a string "cat":

```
mousecatdog.txt
dogcowfox.gif
dogmousecat.txt
dogmousepig.txt
```

So I'd like to get only `dogmousepig.txt` from this list.

I tried to use negative lookaheads, but I am getting an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Of course looked at other threads on the forum, and tried to fix the problem by adding parentheses () or enabling `shopt -s extglob`, but to no avail.

I'm using mac and the script is in bash.

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for FILE in ^((?!cat).)*.txt
     do
      printf "\$FILE\n" 
     done
```

Comment: Try adding an `if`: `for FILE in *.txt; do
   if [[ "$FILE" != *cat* ]]; then
     echo "$FILE"
   fi;
done `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash uses wildcard expansion, not regular expressions in your example.

I see two fairly easy solutions:

1- use a wildcard for the positive selection and an RE for the negative selection, just like @Wiktor Stribizew said in his comment:

```
for FILE in *.txt; do
   if [[ ! $FILE =~ cat ]]; then
      printf "$FILE\n" 
   fi
done
```

2- grep out the output of the wildcard expansion (although this won't work correctly if there are spaces in your file names):

```
for FILE in `\ls -1 *.txt | grep -v cat`; do
   printf "$FILE\n"
done
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use regular expressions after `in`, but you can use glob patterns. With `shopt -s extglob`, you can use the extended patterns:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*cat*).txt ; do
    printf "$f\n"
done
```

To prevent the pattern from expanding to itself when there are no matching files, you need to enable `nullglob`, too.

Comment: Thanks! But with this I also get the error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk: Have you enabled `extglob`?